# How to hide all classes but one on touch swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swipe

So I'm building a site where I have one large article with multiple sections but broken int 4 classes ***Title, Book1, Book2, & Book3*** and I want to be able to swipe and turn `display:none` for all but one and then swipe and do that again. I'm trying to use Hammer.js atm but it doesn't seem to be working. It will start on the ***Title*** class and then swipe to show book1 and keep other hidden (and I need to find out how to have it jump to the top again, but I'm pretty sure that's an easier fix, maybe).

**HTML**

```
<article>
<section class='title'>
</section>
<section class='book1'>
</section>
<section class='book1'>
</section>
.
.
.
<section class='book2'>
</section>
<section class='book2'>
</section>
.
.
.
<section class='book3'>
</section>
<section class='book3'>
</section>
</article>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".title").hammer().on(swipeleft, function(event){
        $('.book1').css("display", "block");
        $('.title').css("display", "none");
    });
    $(".book1").hammer().on(swipeleft, function(event){
        $('.book2').css("display", "block");
        $('.book1').css("display", "none");
    });
    $(".book2").hammer().on(swiperight, function(event){
        $('.book1').css("display", "block");
        $('.book2').css("display", "none");
    });
    $(".book2").hammer().on(swipeleft, function(event){
        $('.book3').css("display", "block");
        $('.book2').css("display", "none");
    });
    $(".book3").hammer().on(swiperight, function(event){
        $('.book2').css("display", "block");
        $('.book3').css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.book1, .book2, .book3 {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use data- attributes to simplify this ?

```
<section class='book2' data-leftitem="book1" data-rightitem="book3">
</section>
```

Then in js if it's a swipeleft set the sender to display:none and set data-leftitem to display:block. Likewise with swiperight using data-rightitem

Comment: Isn't that just doing the exact same thing I'm trying to do with classes but using data tag instead?